# Image pixel scaling error - calculating SNR of CCD lens

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, type-conversion

I am trying to calculate the signal to noise ratio of two loaded images taken from the same digital camera. The idea is to calculate the signal to noise at numerous light levels to achieve a graph that shows the signal to noise ratio of the CCD lens.

The problem that I am facing at the moment is that; when I scale the second image (image B) to have the same average pixel intensity as the first image (image A), the value achieved is not the exact value as the first image. I think that the problem is the result of a rounding error from the image conversions.

The method I use to calculate SNR is:

1. Convert images to gray scale
2. Convert images to 16 bit signed
3. Subtract image B from A
4. Get the average pixel intensity of the subtraction
5. Subtract that average value from A and B (to eliminate some noise)
6. Convert back to 8 bit unsigned
7. Get average pixel values of both images
8. Get ratio of those average values
9. **Scale image B (16 bit unsigned) with the ratio to get average pixel value of image A - Problem area**
10. Convert back to 8 bit and calculate average pixel intensity
11. Subtract images from each other again to eliminate last random noise
12. Calculate standard deviation of this subtraction
13. Convert standard deviation to variance

I am new at OpenCV and programming in general, so any better methods and help on the specific problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
float mean_A;
float mean_B1;
float var,mean_B;
float grey_B_mul;
float grey_sub2;
float o, standard, r;

IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("J:\\backup\\fotos\\IMG_0168.JPG", 3);//Define images
IplImage *img2 = cvLoadImage("J:\\backup\\fotos\\IMG_0164.JPG", 3);
IplImage *grayA = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *grayB = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *gray1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *gray1S = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *gray2S = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *gray2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *sub1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *imgA = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *imgA1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *imgA1U = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *imgB1U = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *imgB1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *imgB = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *imgB_mul = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *imgB_mull = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *imgB_scaled = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *imgBsc = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *sub2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1);
IplImage *sub2U = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
IplImage *sub2_final = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);


if (img->nChannels ==3)
{
    cvCvtColor(img, grayA, CV_BGR2GRAY);    //convert to grayscale
cvCvtColor(img2, grayB, CV_BGR2GRAY);
}
else
{
    cvCopyImage(img,grayA);
cvCopyImage(img2,grayB);
}

CvScalar m = cvAvg(grayA, 0);   //Calculate average pixel intensity
double z = m.val[0];
CvScalar n = cvAvg(grayB, 0);   //Calculate average pixel intensity
double y = n.val[0];

if (z > 128)            //Convert to 16 bit signed
{
    cvConvertScale(grayA, gray1, 256.0, -32768);
    cvConvertScale(gray1, gray1S, 1.0);
}
else
    cvConvertScale(grayA, gray1S, 256.0, -32768);

if (y> 128)
{
    cvConvertScale(grayB, gray2, 256.0, -32768);
    cvConvertScale(gray2, gray2S, 1.0);
}
else
    cvConvertScale(grayB, gray2S, 256.0, -32768);


cvNamedWindow("CCD noise",1);
cvNamedWindow("Image A",1);
cvNamedWindow("Image B scaled",1); 


cvSub(gray1S,gray2S, sub1);     //Subtract images
cvSub(gray1S,sub1, imgA1);
cvSub(gray2S,sub1, imgB1);

cvConvertScale(imgA1, imgA1U, 1.0, +32768 );
cvConvertScale(imgB1, imgB1U, 1.0, +32768 );
cvConvertScale(imgA1U, imgA, 1.0/256);
cvConvertScale(imgB1U, imgB, 1.0/256);
CvScalar d = cvAvg(imgB, 0);                                //Calculate average pixel intensity
mean_B = d.val[0];

CvScalar e = cvAvg(imgA, 0);                                //Calculate average pixel intensity
mean_A = e.val[0];

printf("Image A pixel intensity = %f\n", mean_A);
printf("Image B pixel intensity = %f\n", mean_B);

r = mean_A/mean_B;                                          // Ratio between average pixel intensities of image A and B
printf("r = %f\n", r);


for( int a = 0; a < imgB1U->height; a++ )                   //Scale image B to achieve same average pixel intensity as image A
{  
    for( int b = 0; b < imgB1U->width; b++ )
    {   
        CvScalar pixel = cvGet2D(imgB1U, a, b); 
        o = pixel.val[0]*r;
        CvScalar p;
        p.val[0] = o;
        cvSet2D(imgB_mul, a, b, p);
    }
}
cvConvertScale(imgB_mul, imgBsc, 1.0/256);                  //Convert back to 8 bit

CvScalar c = cvAvg(imgBsc, 0);                              //Calculate average pixel intensity
mean_B1 = c.val[0];                                     

printf("Image B intensity after scaling = %f\n", mean_B1);

cvConvertScale(imgB_mul, imgB_scaled, 1.0, -32768);

cvSub(imgA1,imgB_scaled, sub2);                             //Final subtraction to calculte standard deviation

cvConvertScale(sub2, sub2U, 1.0, +32768 );
cvConvertScale(sub2U, sub2_final, 1.0/256);

CvScalar t,std;
cvAvgSdv(sub2_final, &t, &std);                             //Calculate std deviation
standard = std.val[0];
var = (standard*standard)/2;                                //Square std deviation and devide by 2 for variance

printf("Variance camera noise is = %f\n", var);

cvShowImage("Image A",imgA);
cvShowImage("Image B scaled",imgBsc);
cvShowImage("CCD noise",sub2);
cvWaitKey(0);                                   //To terminate images
cvDestroyWindow("CCD gain");
cvDestroyWindow("Image A");
cvDestroyWindow("Image B scaled");
cvReleaseImage(&img);
cvReleaseImage(&img2);
cvReleaseImage(&gray1);
cvReleaseImage(&gray1S);
cvReleaseImage(&gray2S);
cvReleaseImage(&gray2);
cvReleaseImage(&sub1);
cvReleaseImage(&sub2);
cvReleaseImage(&imgA);
cvReleaseImage(&imgA1);
cvReleaseImage(&imgA1U);
cvReleaseImage(&imgB);
cvReleaseImage(&imgB1);
cvReleaseImage(&imgB1U);
cvReleaseImage(&imgB_mul);
cvReleaseImage(&imgB_mull);
cvReleaseImage(&imgBsc);
cvReleaseImage(&imgB_scaled);
cvReleaseImage(&sub2U);
cvReleaseImage(&sub2_final);

return 0;
}
```

The results of this program are:

Image A pixel intensity = 138.292328

Image B pixel intensity = 253.836456

Ratio = 0.544809

Image B intensity after scaling = 138.351196

Variance of CCD noise = 8.016509

I used different images for the presentation here to put emphasis on what is supposed to happen. In testing images will be much closer (ratio will be around 0.992).

Comment: If you want the average to come out exactly the same you'll need to use floating point rather than integers. Also I'd say your test image B is suspect, the average level of 253.8 is too close to the maximum of 255 and you're probably clipping a significant portion of the pixels - any S/N calculated from that signal will be worthless.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any way to convert the loaded images to signed floating point images, so I can perhaps convert all of them to floating rather than integers? I am just scared that the images will clip when the pixel values go below 0. As for the strange pixel value for B, I think it is because the images were so far apart. B is much lighter than A, so the difference would have been a large negative value. It was just to illustrate the problem clearly. Normal values for A and B are usually around 12 when I am using black bias images.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used OpenCV so I can't help with specifics.

Comment: Oh okay, but thanks anyway.